# A node.js server for both web and mobile app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unity-game-engine, socket.io

I am creating a game by Unity and I want to upload the players' score to MongoDB. Therefore, I have built a node.js server listening to port 3000, and the scores will be sent to the server and store into the database.

My question is that if I want to create a website for viewing/analyzing players' scores, which approach should I use?

1. create two node.js servers, one for the web, one for the game
2. one node.js server but listen to port 80 and 3000 (im not sure whether it is possible or not)
3. any other better suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create one Node server, one to serve both api and web requests.

It sounds like the data served by the API and the web will be the same or subsets of each other. So you'll probably want to share code, lookup the same stuff from the database, etc etc.

From here, you could either create separate routes that the api uses and the web uses (`/api/v1/my_scores` vs `/my_scores`) OR realize that you're just asking for different representations of the same data and do something RESTful like [checking the accept header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23352006/224334) and either sending server rendered HTML or sending JSON back to the client.

Alternatively, you could just create a api in Node, then use a purely front end tool like Angular or React to create a web front end for your site.

Answer (score 0):

Using port 3000 is not a good idea because many users access internet through firewalls which block non-standard ports.

I would recommend using 443 port and https to secure the communication for both use cases.

If the site for analyzing scores does not share logic with the api server, then it can be created as a separate site - but in starting it is easier to manage a single application.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question easily and according to my limited knowledge i think that you don't require more than one server with a database. The reason is that one web you only want to display the high score nor the end user can insert it anything on website. So the complexity is minimal already so don't bother to create another server. Just make data getting API separate for using in website.